# How to 32- or 64-byte align ARM assembly code for use with Xcode/gcc?

Tags: xcode, assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

I have some assembly code that I need to align to a 32 or preferably 64-byte boundary.

I have two scenarios: Aligning the beginning of a function, or having the assembler automatically insert no-ops to align the beginning of a loop.

Are these possible?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

just use

```
.align 64
```

and the assembler should insert nops to the next 64-byte boundary, if not already aligned.

Comment: All right, wasn't sure what the case was for gcc+arm. Updating answer.

Comment: You actually want `.align 6`; The iOS assembler uses the base-2 log of the alignment in `.align`.

Comment: If you want to be unambiguous, always use .balign, which specifies bytes only. Unfortunately, whether .align is a shift or number of bytes depends on the target architecture and tools (non-gcc/clang).